# Apache header editing

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy, http-headers

I have setup with apache (apache 2.4, redhat 7.6) reverse proxy in front of the JVM. 
Apache has basic authentication setup  on it.

The problem is that  Apache header with info about  basic authentication is being sent to the JVM itself. I would need a way to edit the apache header before its sent to the JVM so instead of

```
Auhorization: Basic some_text_goes_here, Bearer  some_text_goes_here
```

I get only this sent to the JVM

```
Auhorization: Bearer  some_text_goes_here
```

Is there a way to strip the Basic authentication information from the header before its sent to the JVM ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`RequestHeader`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html#requestheader) directive to replace the header before it is sent to the backend server.

```
RequestHeader set Auhorization "Bearer some_text_goes_here"
```

If you want to actually remove part of the header string, you can use `edit` along with a regular expression.

```
RequestHeader edit Auhorization "Basic[^,]+, " ""
```

The regex is looks for the string "Basic", followed by one ore more characters that are not a comma, followed by a comma and a space and replaces it with an empty string. This is however just a guess, since we don't know what exactly is in your request header you will have to figure the correct regular expression for this yourself.

Comment: Hi @gerald-schneider,I was looking at that but not sure in which way can I fetch the content for the "some_text_goes_here" from the original header to set it again before sending it to the JVM ?

Comment: Your question sounded like you just have to give a static authorization string to your backend server, hence the simple `set`. I've added an example for `edit` with a basic regular expression.

Comment: thnx, thats it! :)